# BigNumber and empty input field

Tags: javascript

Is there a fast way to prevent errors when an input field is empty using BigNumber plugin?

For example now i'm using this check everytime, for every inputs:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="in1">
<input type="text" value="" id="in2">
<input type="text" value="" id="result" readonly>
<a id="btn">CALCULATE</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").on("click", function(){
    var in1 = $("#in1").val();
    if ( in1 != "" ) {
        in1 = new BigNumber(in1);
    } else { in1 = 0; }  
    var in2 = $("#in2").val();
    if ( in2 != "" ) {
        in2 = new BigNumber(in2);
    } else { in2 = 0; }
    result = in1.plus(in2);
    $("#result").val(result);     
});

 });
 </script>
```

I'm looking for a fast way to prevent error, with a smaller syntax like:

```
in1 = (new BigNumber(in1) == is_valid_operation) ? new BigNumber(in1) : 0;
```

where `is_valid_operation` I mean is not empty and is a valid number.

Comment: $("#id1") should be $("#in1")  and $("#id2") should be $("#in2")

Comment: Yes sorry i've wrong the example, but the request is the same, i'm looking for a better syntax

Comment: If (in1 === 0) you set in1 = 0; Is ist possible to call plus from 0???  I think it should be: in1 = new BigNumber(in1 !== '' ? int2 : "0");  Or: let helper = in1; if(in1 === '') { helper = "0" }  in1 = new BigNumber(helper);

Answer (score 1):

For instance:

```
in1 = new BigNumber(in1 !== '' ? int2 : "0");
```

Or easier to read:

```
in1 = getBigNumber(in1);
function getBigNumber(value)
    let helper = value; 
    if (!value || value === '') { 
        helper = "0" 
    } 
    return new BigNumber(helper);
}
```